# kubectl ingress edit overridden but can't find by what

Tags: edit, kubernetes-ingress, kubectl, ansible-awx

I'm deploying an AWX on a K8S cluster with awx-operator and a GitHub repository that I found (https://github.com/kurokobo/awx-on-k3s) which can work with K8S too.

So everything works good during deployment, except that I have to force PostgreSQL pod deployment on a specific worker node cause it use Persistent Volumes.

Anyway, once my deployment is okay, I want to edit my awx-ingress with the command:

```
kubectl edit -n awx ing awx-ingress
```

And I've added to my file :

```
    status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 172.16.100.5
```

Instead of :

```
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

But even I'm doing this, when I edit the configuration again, my changes are not applied to the configuration and I get the original configuration with loadBalancer: {}.

So I tried to check deployment and statefulset but nothing should override this value.